# Python 3.x - How to get the contents of the variables from the file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file named myfile.conf

```
var1 = 'foo'
var2 = 'bar'
var3 = 'other text'
```

How to get the contents of the variables from the file ?

in Pythnon

```
print(var1)
foo
print(var2)
bar
print(var3)
other text
```

I've tried

```
f = open(/myfile.conf', 'r')
print(f.var1)
print(f.var2)
print(f.var3)
```

Thank you to help

Comment: Have you tried [reading the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)? Do you trust the file contents? If so, you could just import it.

Comment: Read the file, split with `=`, make a dictionary and do things.

Comment: Import it, look at `dir`, and then for anything of interest, just do `getattr(mymodule, variable)`.

Comment: Read this : - https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could read it in as a dictionary:

```
d = {}
with open("myfile.conf", 'r') as f :
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        key,value = line.split('=')
        d[key.strip()] = value.strip().replace("'","")
```

You could then get the variables by accessing the dictionary:

```
print(d['var1']) 
'foo'
```

Comment: Thank you, and what if there is a blank line ?

Comment: `if not line.strip(): continue` before setting key and value

Comment: You can not please modify your code ? I do not know the exact position. Thank you very much.

Comment: Super. Thank you. And to remove the apostrophe is this the right solution ?print(d['set_user_title'].replace('\'', ''))

Comment: @SatNet That should work, yes. I can modify the answer to take this into account

Answer (score 0):

Does the file need to be a .conf file? Why not a .py. Then it would just be
from myfile import *

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by exec() command. example:

```
f = open("myfile.conf", "rb")
for i in f:
    exec(i)
```